# MySQL - Limit results on join

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I cant find how to get the 5 last prices for all actions I'm following. Here is the DB :

ISIN table :

```
 mnemonic | name | toFollow
```

Prices table

```
mnemonic | date | price
```

How can I get the 5 last prices for each ISIN where toFollow = 1 ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Include sample data set relevant to your question with proper table definitions

Comment: use order by and LIMIT 5

Comment: This is such a common question on SO that it has its own tag called `greatest-n-per-group`. The two linked questions provide lots of different ways to get the results you are looking for. Pick one based on your requirements.

Comment: This should help https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score -2):

Just need to order by date and then limit to 5:

```
select a.mnemonic,b.date,b.price
from isin as a
     join isin b on (a.mnemonic=b.mnemonic)
where a.tofollow=1
order by b.date
limit 5;
```

Comment: Question is *How can I get the 5 last prices **for each ISIN** where toFollow = 1*, Also note i am not the down voter here

Comment: I change the order of the join, now you get it

Comment: Again this will not work because it will return only 5 records , Not 5 records for each isin